# Select form Type only post the first option

Tags: forms, symfony

Symfony version: `Symfony 2.1.7-DEV.`

I have a form with a select field, now if I select multiple options he only post the first option.

I have a form type like this:

```
    $builder->add( 'weeks', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'VM\NameBundle\Entity\CaravanRow',
        'property' => 'line',
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er ) use ( $caravan ) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('w')
                      ->orderBy('w.dateFrom', 'ASC')
                      ->where('w.caravan = :caravan' )
                      ->andWhere('w.visible = 1')
                      ->setParameter( 'caravan', $caravan );
        },
        'attr' => array(
            'multiple' => true,
            'size'     => 5,
            'style'    => 'width: 415px;'
        )
    ));
```

Now in the select form on the site looks like this:

```
<select id="reservation_weeks" style="width: 415px;" size="5" multiple="1" required="required" name="reservation[weeks]">
    <option value="1">20 - 11-05 t/m 18-05 (2013)</option>
    <option value="2">21 - 18-05 t/m 25-05 (2013)</option>
    <option value="3">22 - 25-05 t/m 01-06 (2013)</option>
    <option value="4">23 - 01-06 t/m 08-06 (2013)</option>
    <option value="5">24 - 08-06 t/m 15-06 (2013)</option>
</select>
```

Should `reservation[weeks]` not be `reservation[weeks][]`?

Thnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must add option multiple but not in attr array

```
$builder->add( 'weeks', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'VM\NameBundle\Entity\CaravanRow',
    'property' => 'line',
     ....
    'multiple' => true
```